# How to Reset Form through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form created dynamically and I have pulled form values back.

On an Html page I have have used `<button id='btnRoster' class="rainbow-button">Submit!</button>`.

And I have used javascript eventListner to pull the form values.
`document.getElementById('btnRoster').addEventListener('click',dostuffRoster);`

where `dostuffRoster` is the function with collects the form values.

But my problem is that I am unable to reset the form values after submit is clicked.

I have used `document.getElementById("#myForm").reset();` to reset the form but it does nothing.

Here is my complete code of collecting the form values :-

```
 function dostuffRoster()
  {
   
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getData).loadRoster();
  }
  
  function getData(dataArray) {
  
   var userinfoRoster = {};
   userinfoRoster.Shift = [];
   userinfoRoster.Week1 = []; 
   userinfoRoster.Week2 = [];
   
   
  for (var i=0; i<dataArray.length;i++) 
 
  {
 
  //userinfoRoster.Shift = 
  
   var radiosS1 = document.getElementById("s-1" + dataArray[i]);
   var radiosS2 = document.getElementById("s-2" + dataArray[i]);
   var radiosS3 = document.getElementById("s-3" + dataArray[i]);
        if (radiosS1.checked == true)
       { userinfoRoster.Shift[i] = "S1"} 
        else if (radiosS2.checked == true)
       { userinfoRoster.Shift[i] = "S2"}
       else if (radiosS3.checked == true)
       { userinfoRoster.Shift[i] = "S3"}
       else {userinfoRoster.Shift[i] = "S1"}
  userinfoRoster.Week1[i] = document.getElementById('w1-'+dataArray[i]).value;
  userinfoRoster.Week2[i] = document.getElementById('w2-'+dataArray[i]).value;

  }
  
                  google.script.run.userClickedRoster(userinfoRoster);                
   
document.getElementById("#myForm").reset(); // this does nothing
               
          }
```

How can I reset the Form?

Comment: Any help is appreciated I am kinda stuck in this code for a long time.

Comment: What did you try to accomplish your goal? The form creation and other stuff are irrelevant to the question "How to submit form from client to server using Google apps script"? Have you done any research? Any attempts? Provide [mre], i.e, Make a small form(Start from scratch) with a single input and try to receive it in server side and then try to write that to sheets. Read apps script documentation guide.

Comment: @TheMaster I let me explain here I can read and write a form input if its not created dynamically. Because I know the form element for exmaple creating a function like `onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).itemAdd(this.parentNode)"` and then calling those values on server side function like `function itemAdd2(form) {//do something here}` its easy when the inputs are not dynamically created because I know the Ids. Also getting dynamically created radio values etc. these particular subjects are not available on doing google.

Comment: Its not like I just simply copy paste the data I am still in learning phase I am well versed in server side manipulation but have little knowledge of html side java-script. I hope you understand. I have been searching google for solution from morning. Stack over flow is my last option.

Comment: If could make me understand 1 doubt  Does `event` consist of all the form value in array?.

Comment: *its easy when the inputs are not dynamically created because I know the Ids.*  Then that should be your question instead of a full form and code that is irrelevant to the question. To answer, Dynamic creation doesn't matter. As long as input elements have `name` and `value` attributes, they're sent to the server as a form object`{name:value}`, when you send the form element `#myform`. The mdn page I linked earlier explains the quirks of ``radio`` inputs and it's ``value`` attributes.  Read [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: *I have been searching google for solution from morning. Stack over flow is my last option*. 1.Show off your attempts/research efforts. 2.Provide [mre],minimal simple clear reproducible problem instead of dumping all your code. If your read the link([mre]), the first step is "Restart from scratch". That's what's expected of you.

Comment: Got your point let me be back with some edits. Sorry I have a little slow mind.

Comment: @The Master I got success to pull the values back but I am unable to reset the form values. your help is needed I also edited my Question.

Comment: Next time, When it's a completely different question, ask a different question instead. You could answer the old question with your own answer/solution, that might help others like you [see [answer]]and ask a new question instead of changing the original question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

There is no element with `id`: `#myForm`

#### Solution:

You probably meant `myForm`. CSS selectors must be used with `document.querySelector()`.

#### Snippet:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```